404 Error in CodeIgniter Application After Setting Up Virtual Host on Apache (Ubuntu)
I'm trying to set up my old CodeIgniter-based admin application on a new PC running Ubuntu and Apache. The structure of my application is as follows:
apps
   - api_user
       - application
       - public_html
   - web_admin
       - application
       - public_html

I've set up a virtual host for the web_admin part of the application. Here’s my Apache virtual host configuration:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.app-dev
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myapp/apps/web_admin/public_html/"
    <Directory "/var/www/myapp/apps/web_admin/public_html/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

I’ve also updated the /etc/hosts file:
127.0.0.3    admin.app-dev

The app loads the login page fine, but when I try to submit the login form, it makes a request to http://admin.app-dev/admin_api/login, which results in a 404 Not Found error.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Verified that the mod_rewrite module is enabled.
Checked that the .htaccess file in the public_html directory contains the necessary rewrite rules:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


Ensured that the base URL in the CodeIgniter config.php is set to http://admin.app-dev/.
Verified that the routes.php file has the correct routes for admin_api/login.
Checked the Apache error logs (/var/log/apache2/error.log), but no errors are being logged.
Set the ENVIRONMENT to development in CodeIgniter’s index.php file to enable detailed error reporting, but no additional information appears.

However, when I try to access http://admin.app-dev/index.php/admin_api/login, it works, which suggests that URL rewriting might be the issue. But all necessary rewrite rules seem to be in place.
My environment:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Apache version: 2.4.52
PHP version: 8.1
CodeIgniter version: 3.x

Additional Information:

Permissions and ownership for the public_html directory and files are set to www-data:www-data, with 755 permissions.
This same setup worked perfectly on my old development machine.

Question:
Why does the URL http://admin.app-dev/admin_api/login result in a 404 error, and how can I resolve this issue to restore the URL rewriting functionality?

If the Apache error log does not record a 404 error for this, then that suggests the rewriting actually worked, and it is codeigniter that is responding with the 404 status code.
